# How to validate fields of form with in play framework

Tags: validation, playframework, formatting

I want to make things like put masks and validate using regular expression, or using other way, verify if field is empty, and many other things, in a play form.

For example:

```
@inputText(
    myForm("anydata"),
    'id -> "anyData",
    '_label -> "Any Data"
)
```

I want to put a mask of only characters/numbers/etc, and put a mask to format this field. Have some helper of play framework to do this, or some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation is pretty simple in Play! You will have to implement this on the Form object.
From the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Defining-constraints-on-the-form):

```
val userFormConstraints2 = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "age" -> number(min = 0, max = 100)
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)
)
```

The age field has a validation for min and max number values. You could roll your own custom validation. I've had to do something like to this:

```
"pairs" -> seq(text).verifying(pairs => pairs.forall(pair => pair.contains(':')))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are mentioning putting masks I assume that you want to use some JavaScript - client side - pre-validation. There's nothing to do with Play in this subject, you can/need just to find proper plugin which does the thing within the browser, i.e. [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

You will need to validate this on the server side as well (for better security) anyway in such case you need to create own validator which respects the same rules as the client side one.

Comment: Exactly, so can you tell me how I can use form helpers and JavaScript code, or even pure html code without any helpers, and how to get this values in the controller?